# Laravel Eloquent ORM Relationships

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, orm

I have a issue with Eloquent ORM relationship i have company Model and Countries Model, One to Many relationship, I have used following codes.

**Company Model**

```
    class Company_model extends Model
    {
        public $table = "company";
        public $primaryKey = "id";

        public function countries(){
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Countries','country','countryId');
        }
    }
```

**Countries Model**

```
class Countries extends Model
{
    public $table = "countries";
    public $primaryKey = "countryId";


}
```

i have used the following code to retrieve the data i want to get company details along with countryName

```
$companyObj = new Company_model();

$result = $companyObj::with('countries')->get();
```

i get the results with company and countries details but the countries details come as an array i need it come without array also i need to take the country Name now all the details in the countries table comes to the array.

**Now Result**

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [companyName] => Test [address] => [country] => 1 [phone] => [email] => [website] => [companyImg] => 1 [create_by] => [create_time] =>  [countries] => Array ( [countryId] => 1 [countryName] => Test [currency] => [language] => ) ) )
```

**I need the result like**

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [companyName] => Test [address] => [phone] => [email] => [website] => [companyImg] => 1 [create_by] => [create_time] =>  [countryName] => Test  ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

You've to add a new method in `Company_model` that's have the method that only give the selected fields.

```
class Company_model extends Model
    {
        public $table = "company";
        public $primaryKey = "id";

        public function countries(){
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Countries','country','countryId');
        }
    }
```

This is the new method.

```
public function countriesIDs()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Countries')->select(['name']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$result = $companyObj::with('countries')->get()->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can to do this:

```
$result = Company_model::leftjoin('countries', 'countries.id', '=', 'company.countryId')->select('company.*', 'countries.countryName')->get();
```

I hope it would helpful.

Comment: Yeah i tried this before it work fine. but i thought using ORM relationship is more faster in performance that's why i want to try with ORM relationship

Comment: In ORM relationship, when you get code the ...... Company_model::with('countries')->get(); ......... It automatically add the relationship array with the name of 'countries' to your Model object because one company has many countries.

Comment: So, if you want just country name in the countries array to your main array, so you can join the table and select specific columns to show in the main array.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible by laravel "with" query. You have to get it by join query like:

```
Company_model::join('countries','countries.countryId','=','company.country')->select('company.*','countries.countryName')->get();
```

Comment: Why do you same the answer?

Comment: Yeah i tried this before it work fine. but i thought using ORM relationship is more faster in performance that's why i want to try with ORM relationship